# Is there a way to randomize which index of a list gets printed in python?

Tags: python

I would like to randomize an output from a list.

I tried using a random and an index but i keep getting a tuple error.

code:

```
letters = (*list of letters a-z)

a = random(0,25)

print(letters(a))
```

I believe it should be a random letter. But as I said it gives a tuple error.

Comment: You need to use index notation, not parentheses (`[a]`).

Comment: To access an element, use brackets: `letters[a]`. Also see [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).

Comment: Please provide your **real** code, your first line is far from being valid Python, which makes me wonder if your real problem is even in what you wrote here. Also, see how to provide a [mcve], and note that you should always include your complete error traceback if your code produces an error.

Comment: I suggest you to look at `random.choice` function.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. You must `import random` at the top
2. Lists are defined with square backets, not round ones.
3. You need to use the `randint` method from random
4. Again, indexes use square brackets, not round, so a must be enclosed with `[]`, not `()`

Full working code is below minus all the letters of the alphabet as I wasn't going to type them out

```
import random

letters = ['A', 'B', 'D','K']
a = random.randint(0,25)
print(letters[a])
```

**An alternative version which provides the letters automatically**

```
import random
import string
letter_set = string.ascii_uppercase
a = random.randint(0,25)
print(letter_set[a])
```

Comment: Note that the alphabet can be accessed from `letters.ascii_lowercase` and `ascii_uppercase`, so typing the letters out wouldn't be necessary in this case.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah TIL. Added that to the answer.